# database comparison/ API calls

Tags: database, api, comparison, postman, sql-query-store

I have a scenario where I am comparing 2 databases. One is the central database which I don't have access to and another is my local database which I can access. The developers would be making some API calls to the central database and populating our local database( around 5000 records). After it is done, I would have to compare the records if they are retrieved correctly and that nothing has been missed. Please suggest me the best solution to do this. I have the following in my head - 
A)Make API call to the central database for the key tab and retrieve all the records as a response
 Then make API call to the local data store for the similar entity and then compare both the records (HOW?)

B) Make API call to the central database and after I have got the response for the desired fields write SQL query to compare both..

C) Any other better, quicker and accurate approach?

Thanks

Comment: Can you get a hash of both data dumps and compare them? That'd probably make the task a lot easier.

Comment: sorry but what is getting a hash?